# drupal authentication for iOS swift using waterwheel pod

Tags: ios, swift, drupal

I have installed the pod 'waterewheel' for swift. The problem is that xcode throwing an error as code not supported. It seems this pod was done for swift 2. Can anyone help in mentioning any alternative pod or a resolution for this?

I am trying to authenticate users on drupal through iOS app

Comment: Have You created your project in swift 3 or swift2?

Comment: My project is on Swift 3

Comment: Okay so just go to project target and build setting -> swift-compiler version-> use legacy swift language version -> YES and same thing you have to do in project also

Answer (score 0):

The pod has been update for Swift 3 awhile ago.

Ill get it fixed for Swift 4 this weekend.